# Perimeter of an equilateral triangle drawn with respect to a square.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Here's a question that was asked in the [International Kangaroo Math Contest 2016](http://ikmc.kangaroo.org.pk/). The question goes like this:

> If the perimeter of the square in the figure is 4 units, then what is the perimeter of the equilateral triangle?

[image]

**What I did:**

Well I tried something very naïve and it was the supposition that the equilateral triangle cuts the top side of the square at its midpoint. Hence giving the following result.

[image]

By Pythagoras' Theorem, 
$$\overline{AB} = \overline{MC} = \sqrt{\overline{BC}^2 + \overline{BM}^2} = \sqrt{\left(1\right)^2 + \left(\frac12\right)^2} = \frac{\sqrt5}{2}$$

So perimeter of the triangle is:
$$\begin{align}
P&=\overline{AF} +\overline{FM}+\overline{MC}+\overline{CD}+\overline{DE}+\overline{EA}\\
&= \frac12+\frac12+\frac{\sqrt5}2+1+\frac12+\frac{\sqrt5}2\\
&= \frac52+\sqrt5
\end{align}$$

However this is not the correct answer and I know that the problem is with the supposition that $M$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$. So what is the correct method and answer?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We only need to know that the $\angle ABC=30°$, the rest is just straight forward.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

$M$ is NOT the midpoint of $AB$. Note that the angle $\angle MCB$ is equal to $90^{\circ}-60^{\circ}=30^{\circ}$, therefore 
$$|MB|=|BC|\tan(30^{\circ})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$$
Moreover $|ED|=|MB|$ (why?).
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Wish I'd refreshed before posting my answer, I may have given too much away!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the angle AED is $\frac{\pi}{3}$ radians (or 60 degrees if you prefer). Since the side opposite that angle is $1$, and $\tan(\frac{\pi}{3})$ is $\sqrt{3}$, we know that the side ED must be of length $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.  The triangle MBC is similar to  EAD, so the side MB is also $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$. You can use Pythagorean's Theorem and the fact that each side of the square is 1 to find the lengths of all the remaining sides needed.

Comment: Nice answer. BTW I like your username.

Answer (score 1):

Given a horizontal segment with length $L$ and two lines

$$
\begin{cases}
y_1 = x \tan(\frac{\pi}{2})\\
y_2 = (L-x)\tan(\frac{\pi}{3})
\end{cases}
$$

their intersection is at

$$
y_1=y_2\Rightarrow x = \frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{3})L}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{3})+\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})}
$$

hence the equilateral triangle has perimeter $3L$ and the square has perimeter $4 x = \frac{4L\tan(\frac{\pi}{3})}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{3})+\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})} = \frac{4L\sqrt3}{\sqrt 3+1}$

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the figure, let $x$ and $h$ be half-side and height of equilateral triangle, resp.:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

For the equilateral triangle:
$$h^2+x^2=(2x)^2 \Rightarrow h^2=3x^2 \Rightarrow h=x\sqrt{3}.$$

From the similarity of triangles:
$$\frac{h}{4}=\frac{x}{2x-4} \Rightarrow \frac{x\sqrt{3}}{4}=\frac{x}{2(x-2)} \Rightarrow x=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}+2 \Rightarrow P=6x=4\sqrt{3}+12.$$

**Addendum:** It was stated the perimeter of the square is $4$, not the side. So, the answer must be divided by $4$ to get $3+\sqrt{3}$.